# Using Perforce C# API, how do I check whether a change list was integrated to other branches

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

For example, I have branch //source/b1/... and //source/b2/...
I checked in a change list @123 to b1 branch. I would like to write a tool to check whether @123 was integrated to b2 using perforce C# API.
Image I need check in many change lists to b1, so this tool can help me to monitor whether any change list not integrated to b2, then I can decide whether perform the integration.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use 'p4 interchanges', as in 'p4 interchanges //source/b1/... //source/b2/...'.

Another way to do this would be to use 'p4 integrate -n', as in 'p4 integrate -n //source/b1/... //source/b2/...'.